# Shikashi: cannot access constant Hash exception

Tags: ruby

Why do I get the Security Error **"cannot access constant Hash"** in this scenario using the Shikashi Gem?

```
include Shikashi

privileges = Privileges.new
privileges.instances_of(Hash).allow_all
Sandbox.new.run(privileges, "arguments=Hash.new;")
```

Any insights? I need to run some ruby code in a Sandbox to see if its behaves nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the script to [read the `Hash` constant](http://tario.github.io/shikashi/doc/classes/Shikashi/Privileges.html#M000021). You’ll also need to allow [calling the `new` method on the `Hash` object](http://tario.github.io/shikashi/doc/classes/Shikashi/Privileges.html#M000007):

```
include Shikashi

privileges = Privileges.new
privileges.allow_const_read "Hash"
privileges.object(Hash).allow :new
privileges.instances_of(Hash).allow_all
Sandbox.new.run(privileges, "arguments=Hash.new;")
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you. Changed this to allow all hash methods to work:
privileges.object(Hash).allow_all

Comment: While we are at it;) Is there a way of saying allow_all except this methods?

Comment: I got it, easy:  privileges.object(Hash).allow Hash.new.methods.reject{ |name| name=~/delete/ }